# Dynamically added link button disappeared on button click leaving an empty column

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic-controls

The datagrid reads from several xml files, so I create the columns dynamically, and added a templatefield as the last column.

A link button is added in the templatefield using RowDataBound.

```
Private Sub GridItem_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridItem.RowDataBound
    Try
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim linkb As New LinkButton
            linkb.Text = "Delete"
            linkb.ID = "LinkDeleteItem"
            linkb.OnClientClick = "javascript:DeleteItem('" & Convert.ToString(e.Row.RowIndex) & "')"
            e.Row.Cells(GridItem.Columns.Count - 1).Controls.Add(linkb)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Everything works fine.

But when I click a button outside the gridview, to open a window to add a new item to the grid, the linkbuttons disappear. But the column is still there.

If I just close the new window without saving a new data (which will prompt the grid to rebind), the column remains empty. I had to reload the gridview for the linkbuttons to appear.

Is it because the linkbuttons are created on rowdatabound? How should I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried only binding the grid the first time the page is loaded  by using `If Not IsPostBack` in `Page_Load` sub-routine?

Comment: The grid is loaded when the user chooses which xml file to open. So when the page is first loaded, the grid is empty.

Comment: So what causes the grid to re-bind when you click a button outside the grid view?

Comment: I'm not sure myself, actually. When I click the button, the data remains bound, but the linkbuttons are missing.

Comment: If you put a break point on `RowDataBound` event, when does the break point get hit?

Comment: it didn't get to that event when the button's clicked, and it didn't get to the sub where the grid's populated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the `OnRowDataBound` event of GridView is NOT called on next postback. This happens because by default viewstate of GridView is set true  i.e. `EnableViewState` property of Gridview is `true`. When ViewState is on, Gridview stores data from the same and `OnRowDataBound` event is not called. Also, at this point View state will not be applied for your `linkButtons` as they aren't created in `page_load`.

Try setting `EnableViewState` property to false for your gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" 
     OnRowDataBound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound"
     EnableViewState="false"
  ....  />
```

OR you can also bind your `GridView` in `page_Load` as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       CustomersGrIdView.DataBind();
    }
```

Now after every postback your `OnRowDataBound` event will be called and hence the `LinkButtons` will be available everytime.

---

**NOTE:** Setting `EnableViewState` property to false for gridview  can be a bad practice to an extent, especially in scenarios of heavy data usages. Same goes for Binding gridview every time.

When using dynamic controls, they exist only until the next postback.ASP.NET will not re-create a dynamically added control. If you need to re-create a control next time too on postback, you should perform the control creation in the `PageLoad` event handler.

This will give you benefit of using view state with your dynamic control. Even though view state is normally restored before the `Page.Load` event, if you create a control in the handler for the `PageLoad` event, ASP.NET will apply any view state information that it has after the `PageLoad` event handler ends.

Comment: Your explanation helped me think of a way to solve this. I repopulate the grid, which rebinds it, on every postback, after checking whether there are rows in the gridview. But I'm worried if this'll cause any bugs or errors in the future, or if there are a lot of data.

Comment: Yes, you can do that also. Realized that was present in my answer but  actually missing from answer because of my incorrect formatting applied. Corrected now. They are arguably same and won't make much difference. Also, your concern is right. Although this won't cause any bugs or Errors, only issue being that there will always be extra calls to database. However if performance is really not an issue, seeing your requirements this is a good option.

Comment: Then I suppose this is the option that I'll take. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: thanks man after 3 years this is help me ! i searched for hours until i find this and it works well

Comment: I get all of that but what i don't get is why the events for the dynamically created controls are not called. for example if i create a checkbox with an OnCheckChanged event and put a debug point on the click event. it is never triggered. I have the same problems with buttons, DDL, etc.Also the page_load is giving me problems because i need the databound event to already fire as i need it to know what type of control to render. (depends on one columns value)